# Atiyah-Singer index theorem

Tags: differential-topology, topological-k-theory, elliptic-operators

I have seen the cohomological form of the index theorem usually stated in the following form:
$$
\int_X \varphi^{-1}\left(\operatorname{ch}([\sigma(P)])\right).\operatorname{todd}(TX\otimes\mathbb C)
$$
where $\varphi$ is the Thom isomorphism, or as
$$
\int_{T^*X}\operatorname{ch}([\sigma(P)]).\operatorname{todd}(TX\otimes\mathbb C).
$$
My question is: *when are both formulations equivalent and how to show that they are*? (For example, $X$ clearly needs to be orientable in order for the first formulation to make sense ...)

A related point that also bothers me is that the second formulation involves a Todd class of an element of $K^0(X)$ and not $K^0(T^*X).$ Is this to be interpreted as seeing $K^0(T^*X)$ as a right $K^0(X)$-module with the module structure arising by pulling back along the projection map $T^*X\to X?$

And then there is a final little thing that bothers me: sometimes, eg. in the the book "Topology and Analysis: the Atiyah-Singer Index Formula and Gauge-Theoretical Physics" a factor of $(-1)^n$ or similar appears on the RHS, while otherplaces, eg. the Wikipedia page for the index theorem, the correction coefficient is absent. Which is the correct version?

Thanks!